# basic perl: regex statement not working in perl 5.10.1 machine but works in 5.18?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I am testing the following piece of code which compares a wordlist of arrays to a string and searches for matches. The problem is only in the regex statement at the bottom of the code, it doesn't produce any results/matches in on the linux server at school which i am supposed to run/test it on which uses perl 5.10.1. It did seem to run fine on my local windows machine running strawberry perl for some reason?

is there any other way the below regex statement can be modified to achieve the same result on older versions of perl(or have i made a mistake somewhere else)?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my $keyword_file = "keywords.txt"; #converts this to an array @keywords
my $myString = "this string will be loger later; print";

#read keywords
my @keywords;

open (FH, "$keyword_file") or die "Can't open $keyword_file for read: $!";

while (<FH>) {
    chomp;
    push (@keywords, $_);
}
close FH or die "Cannot close $keyword_file: $!";


#compare keywords and file string

foreach (@keywords)
{
    if($myString =~ /$_/){   # having problems here <<***************
    print "foud match";
    }

}
```

the keyword file is just a simple text file which contains single words like print, while, exit ...etc on each line.

keywords.txt:

```
exit
ls
print
grep
```

Comment: add `chomp;` right before `if($myString =~ /$_/){`

Comment: @Matt, he already is.

Comment: Please provide the necessary data to replicate your problem.

Comment: are you referring to the keyword file? just added a part of it in the question^

Comment: Was keywords.txt created in Windows while you are running your script in Linux?

Comment: "loger", "foud" ... Your keyboard's "N" key may be starting to go out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the file on Windows. Windows uses CR LF as line endings. You then transferred it to a unix system without converting the line endings to unix line endings (LF). That means that `$_` contains `exit` plus a carriage return rather than just `exit`.

Fix the line endings (e.g. using `dos2unix`), or handle Windows files on unix systems (replace `chomp;` with `s/\s+\z//;`).

Comment: That could well be it (cross platform file issues). Also make sure you don't have / in your keywords (the keywords.txt entries). If you do, change your delimiters from / to #, ~, or something else not found in keywords.txt. Finally, just for clarity you might try explicitly giving `m/$_/` rather than `/$_/`. It _shouldn't_ make any difference, but I've seen stranger things...

Comment: @Phil Perry, Actually, if you want to treat keywords as strings to match literally rather than regex patterns, you'd use `/\Q$_/`. Changing the delimiter won't help at all.